# How can I optimize video reels in flutter

Tags: flutter, video, video-streaming, video-processing, video-compression

I have a problem with my Flutter app. I want to display the videos in the same way as the Reels section of TikTok. Here is a [screenshot of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRL3K.jpg).

**Problem:**
It contains video reels, but each video takes time to load.

**What I've tried:**
I'm also compressing the videos when they're uploaded to the server. Loading still takes time.

**Code that I'm using:**

```
void _initializeController() async {
  String videoUrl = ConstRes.itemBaseUrl + widget.url!;
  _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(videoUrl);
  final fileInfo = await getCachedVideo(videoUrl);

  if (fileInfo == null) {
    await _controller!.initialize();
    setState(() {
      _controller!.setLooping(true);
      _controller!.play();
      widget.isLoading.call(false);
      widget.function.call(_controller);
    });
    cacheVideo(videoUrl);
  } else {
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.file(fileInfo.file);
    await _controller!.initialize();
    setState(() {
      _controller!.setLooping(true);
      _controller!.play();
      widget.isLoading.call(false);
      widget.function.call(_controller);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Not clear what the **exact** problem is because generally **all data takes time to load**. That part cannot be avoided... The way you can show multiple videos quickly is to have the required (visual) data **already available** when the user swipes to that specific video. How one solves that _"data is already loaded"_ part is down to each coder's own customized solution. For example... Only you know your server's abilities, only you know the stored video resolutions, only you know the typical file sizes to be downloaded... etc.

Comment: PS: As it is currently written, this is **not a programming (code) issue**. This reads more like an engineering (or project planning) issue. You need to engineer (design) a method to get the required video data to be available at user's swiping-to point. Your shown code functions do not recreate the problem of: _"...Cannot load videos like Reels"_ ... When you show code, explain the problem/error of current code and what **the expected result of shown code** is. We can only help to fix shown code. You must engineer your own solutions from research, then ask about the code written towards that